# how can i use fabric js canvas in wordpress

Tags: fabricjs

I have created custom plugin in Wordpress. But canvas not working properly. 
I have created canvas using background image. Its working properly outside.
Whenever I create canvas with background image in Wordpress. Its show with background image but when I click anywhere on canvas background image is lost.
Please see below my code.

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var imgElement = document.getElementById('my-image');
var aspect = imgElement.width / imgElement.height;
img.src = "background.jpg";
canvas.backgroundColor = "#fff";
canvas.backgroundImageStretch = true;
canvas.backgroundImageWidth = 500;
canvas.setBackgroundImage(img.src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
  scaleX: canvas.width / imgElement.width,
  scaleY: canvas.width / (imgElement.height * aspect)
});
canvas.renderAll();
```